# Basic tcolorbox help appreciated

Tags: tcolorbox

I'm not really a LaTeX programmer but have to go through the code of a document that I didn't write, and I'm wondering how to create a very basic box using the `tcolorbox` package. I have the manual that explains how it all works, but it's overwhelming to a LaTeX-noob like myself, so I'm just hoping someone can simplify things for me.

All I want to do is define a particular type of box (call it `\qbox` for example) in the `.sty` document and then call it when I need it. It just needs to be a 5mm square gray box with a white number (title) in it. How can I define and call a simple box like this with `tcolorbox`?

The boxes should look as close to these as possible:

[image: gray boxes]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can do it with the standard `\colorbox`, I think.

Comment: Perfect! I didn't even know about \colorbox but it does the job fine and isn't too complicated to use. I just did \colorbox{gray}{\textcolor{white}{\textbf{\,1\,}}} and it pretty much looks the way I want.

Answer (score 3):

(Principally the frame is stolen from Torbjørn ;-), but this is one way to 
go for `tcolorbox`, defining a total `TCBox`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}


\DeclareTotalTCBox[auto counter,number within=section]{\qbox}{+O{}}{
  enhanced,
  frame hidden,
  sharp corners,
  nobeforeafter,
  colback=gray,
  colupper=white,
  size=small,
  box align=base}{%
  \thetcbcounter% Declare the content immediately, there the box number
}
\begin{document}
\section{Foo}
\qbox{}
And then some text and stuff.
\qbox{}
And so on. \qbox\qbox\qbox\qbox\qbox\qbox\qbox

\section{Bar}
Next section, start again with \qbox.
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Is the size of the box here (the width specifically) defined with the size=small parameter?

Comment: Yes, there are some possible values for `size`. Small is the quickest way, in my point of view, in order to get a small boundary

Answer (score 2):

If all your boxes are numbered sequentially, you can set up a counter to get the number automatically. In the example below I also reset the counter at every `\section`, as a demonstration. If you don't want that, remove the `\counterwithin` line.

[image: output of code]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{chngcntr}

\newcounter{boxnumber}
% reset counter at every \section:
\counterwithin{boxnumber}{section}

\newcommand\qbox{%
  \refstepcounter{boxnumber}%
  \colorbox{gray}{\textcolor{white}{\textbf{\arabic{boxnumber}}}}%
}

\begin{document}
\section{Foo}
\qbox{}
And then some text and stuff.
\qbox{}
And so on. \qbox\qbox\qbox\qbox\qbox\qbox\qbox

\section{Bar}
Next section, start again with \qbox.
\end{document}
```

Comment: This is a great idea - I hadn't even considered the sequential counting as well. Thanks!